# Spring Cache Abstraction Testing

Tags: java, spring, memcached, integration-testing

I don't have to much experience on "**Spring Cache Abstraction**", so I'm not sure if this is even possible.
I have this **MemcachedConfig** class, with **@EnableCaching** annotation.
I need to test the method "**saveSession**"  from **ServiceImpl** class, but I want to *embedded memcached* on the test, so when the method is call, use the one defined on the test, and not the bean on the **applicationContext**. Is that possible?

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class MemcachedConfig {
    ....
    @Bean
    public CacheFactory sessionCacheFactory() {
        ....
    }

    @Bean
    public ExtendedSSMCacheManager cacheManager(List<Cache> caches) {
        ....
    }
}

@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    ....
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Service proxyOfMe;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize()  {
        proxyOfMe = (Service) applicationContext.getBean(Service.class);
    }

    @CachePut(value = VALUE , key = KEY)
        public SessionCache saveSession(String session) {
            ....
    }
    ....
}
```